# Getting Error while running pig script on google Dataproc Cluster, all the parameter are defined correctly

Tags: unix, apache-pig, google-cloud-dataproc

This is my pig script -

```
fs -cp -f gs://$codepath/db_password.sh file://$dataprochome/db_password.sh;
fs -cp -f gs://$codepath/jdbc_daily_load_tables.py file://$dataprochome/jdbc_daily_load_tables.py;
sh chmod +x $dataprochome/db_password.sh;
sh chmod +x $dataprochome/jdbc_daily_load_tables.py;
sh $dataprochome/db_password.sh $dataprochome $stg_gcs_bucket $se_stg_gcs_bucket $target_schema $target_table_stg_gm_add_attributes_orbit $target_table_orbit_delivery_partner_icc $kvenv;
```

All the input variable are defined properly still getting below error

```
2023-02-09 20:05:36,221 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 6.
Was expecting one of:
    IDENTIFIER
    OTHER
    LITERAL
    SHELLCMD
    
Details at logfile: /tmp/17114c5e-af3d-4a09-89c4-324250436a76/pig_1675973135671.log
2023-02-09 20:05:36,240 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 712 milliseconds (712 ms)
```

Comment: Please show your pig script

Comment: you can see in the first part of the question

Comment: No, it isn't...

Answer (score 1):

As per comments in the answer provided by @OneCricketeer, the error was resolved by removing the spaces between the arguments passed to .sh file in the pig script.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bash script. Not [pig](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html) ... If you're running that in `pig`, then that perfectly explains why it's failing to parse that file.

You need to use `sh` rather than `pig` on shell scripts

Comment: No, by this **pig** script I am calling **.sh** file. The issue has been resolved. The issue was the extra space while passing the **arguments** to **sh** one of the argument was null, which has been rectified